# how to handle AWS API gateway for API versions with swagger json in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, aws-api-gateway

We have CICD using cloud formation scripts we build infra and deploy API.
Jenkins file script:

**Step 1:** our swagger will create swagger docs. this will be stored in S3 bucket

```
sh "curl https://{host-name}/v2/api-docs?group=school-api-v1.0 -o ${WORKSPACE}/devl-schoolapi-doc.json"
```

**Step 2:** `sh "aws apigateway put-rest-api --rest-api-id ${env.API_ID} --mode overwrite --body 'file://${WORKSPACE}/devl-schoolapi-doc.json' --region us-east-1"`

**Step 3:** `sh "aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id ${env.API_ID} --stage-name ${env.ENVIRONMENT} --region us-east-1 "}`

This will build on AWS env Gateway with v1/ endpoint for resources.
[Gateway view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPGTS.png)

Now I want to maintain two API versions in this gateway for the below methods.

```
1./student
2./v1/student
```

In my api two swagger json are getting produce. As this is minor version it should have same endpoints

```
1.https://{host-name}/v2/api-docs?group=school-api-v1.0
2.https://{host-name}/v2/api-docs?group=school-api-v1.1
```

Currently with my scripts its showing only the v1.0 version in gateway

Comment: Check if one of these two help you https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-validation-sample-api-swagger.html or here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-extensions-importexport-version.html

Answer (score -1):

```java
public class SwaggerConfig implements OperationBuilderPlugin {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public Docket docketApi() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("rest-api-v1.0")
                .select()
                .paths(paths())
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).build()
                .operationOrdering(new Ordering<Operation>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Operation left, Operation right) {
                        return left.getMethod().name().compareTo(right.getMethod().name());
                    }
                })
                .apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo());

    }

    private ApiInfo apiEndPointsInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title(env.getProperty("env") + env.getProperty("appname"))
                .description(env.getProperty("description")).contact(new Contact(env.getProperty("contact-name"),
                        env.getProperty("contact-url"), env.getProperty("contact-email")))
                .version(env.getProperty("version")).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket docketApi2() {
        ParameterBuilder aParameterBuilder = new ParameterBuilder();
        aParameterBuilder.name("Accept").modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header").defaultValue("application/v1.1+json").required(true).build();
        List<Parameter> operationParameters = new ArrayList<>();
        operationParameters.add(aParameterBuilder.build());
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("rest-api-v1.1")
                .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(env.getProperty("basepackage")))
                .paths(postPaths())
                .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")))
                .build()
                .operationOrdering(new Ordering<Operation>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Operation left, Operation right) {
                        return left.getMethod().name().compareTo(right.getMethod().name());
                    }
                })
                .globalOperationParameters(operationParameters)
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder().title(env.getProperty("env") + env.getProperty("appname"))
                        .description(env.getProperty("description")).contact(new Contact(env.getProperty("contact-name"),
                                env.getProperty("contact-url"), env.getProperty("contact-email")))
                        .version("1.1").build());
    }

    private com.google.common.base.Predicate<String> postPaths() {
        return Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/v1.*"));
    }

    private com.google.common.base.Predicate<String> paths() {
        return or(
                regex("/v1.*"), regex("/health.*"));
    }
}
```